# Use Reflection to set value in class with a protected internal index

Tags: .net, reflection, system.reflection

I have an object whose values I am trying to set via Reflection.

The object has this indexer:

```
protected internal object this[string propertyName] { get; set; }
```

I would like to set a value within this collection - for example, if the instance contains a `name` key, I want to set the value.

If the indexer was `public`, it would look like this: `myObj["Name"] = "foo"`.

Interestingly, if I am in debug mode, I can see the item I want to set `myObj.Item["Name"]`, but if I code
`myObj.GetType().GetProperty("Item")` it returns `Null`.

How can I set this value using Reflection?

Answer (score 0):

To get an internal (or non-public) property using reflection you will need to provide the correct set of `BindingFlags`.

The correct set would be (not limited to)

- `BindingFlags.NonPublic`
- `BindingFlags.Instance`

Such as.

```
var property = myObj.GetType().GetProperty("Item", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

Now to call the set to add a new value you can call.

```
property.SetValue(myObj, "Foo", new object[] { "bar" });
```

This will be equivalant of calling `myObj["Foo"] = "bar";`

To get a value from the indexer you can call.

```
var value = property.GetValue(myObj, new object[] { "Name" });
```

Which will return the value of the object stored with the index key `Name`.

[More on BindingFlags ON MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx).